# Using variable of ngfor in iondidchange - ionic 2

Tags: slider, ionic2, ngfor

Iam learning ionic 2 and actually I got the following situation:

I have a ngfor-loop within ion-slides.
I want to call a function after a slide changed, so I used the (ionDidChange) attribute inside the ion-slides.
My issue is, that I need a local variable of the current slide in my ngfor-loop during this function call, which is not inside that loop and I have no Idea how to handle that.

Here is my Code:

```
<ion-slides effect='slide' [options]="mySlideOptions" #mySlider (ionDidChange)=slideChanged(stuff.id)>
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let stuff of stuffs">
    {{stuff.id}}
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Of course I get an error: "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined", because of the stuff.id in the function call, but I want to show you what I am looking for.

I am sure there has to be a very simple solution, but I dont get it.
Thank you.

Comment: not sure if this would fit but you can get previous and active slide from [slides](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/slides/Slides/#getPreviousIndex) also the event is [ionSlideDidChange](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/slides/Slides/#output-events)

Comment: I tried this. Called slideChanged() without any parameters and used "this.slides". But it seems like it is not possible to use the ngfor-object.

Comment: you will have to associate the slide index with your object list index..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to associate the slide index with your object list index.You can get previous and active slide from slides also the event is `ionSlideDidChange`.

```
<ion-slides effect='slide' [options]="mySlideOptions" #mySlider (ionSlideDidChange)=slideChanged()>
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let stuff of stuffs">
    {{stuff.id}}
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

In the Component:

```
slideChanged(){
let index = this.slides.getPreviousIndex();
let requiredId = this.stuffs[index].id;
}
```